# why is this closure called 1201 times instead of 900?

Tags: swift

I have this activation function:

```swift
protocol Activation {
    var output: [[Double]] { get }
    func forward(inputs:[[Double]])
}

class ReLU: Activation {
    public var output: [[Double]]
    
    init() {
        output = []
    }

    public func forward(inputs:[[Double]]) {
        output = inputs.map{  row in row.map{ val in max(0, val) }  }
    }
}
```

if I pass that `forward` method inputs that are a 100x3 [[Double]], instead of seeing a marker showing it's line of code was run 900 times (or 902), I see 1201. Why is that? would it be faster to use a plain for loop?

Comment: add code where forward func is called

Comment: Did you really mean 100 × 3 = 900? I’m guessing you meant 300 × 3. As Kerstin points out, break that single line of code onto separate lines and you’ll better see what’s going on.

Comment: Benchmark it and you will see immaterial performance b/w `map` and `for` approaches in release builds. In extreme cases you might consider vDSP (see [Clipping, Limit, and Threshold Operations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/clipping_limit_and_threshold_operations)). E.g. with millions records per row, I achieved 30% performance improvement with vDSP’s [`clip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3240862-clip). But in anything other than these extreme situations, the difference will be immaterial and we should avoid premature optimization.

Comment: difference was 0.03 seconds on that size data set. which is surprising given the answer below, but nothing worrying me too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate code a bit to see what is actually happening.

```
output = inputs.map { row in     (1 call)
    row.map { val in             (row count call)
        return max(0, val)       (val in row count call)
    }
}
```

So in you one line you have 1 + 100 + 3*100 = 401 call

For input of 300x3 you will get 1201.

You will get same result if you use for loop.